# How to pick a true color from a texture in vertex paint mode?

Tags: texturing

I can't pick a true color from a vertex paint texture, because its colors depends on perspective of view. I've tried this in vertex paint mode with material shading, but what I get is not a true color. How can I achieve that?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using 2.80, you can go to the shading menu in the 3d view (in solid shading mode) and choose flat instead of studio lighting.

If you're using 2.79 or earlier, wireframe view will actually give you a shadeless view.

Answer (score 0):

Open an UV/Image window, set it to texture paint mode (switch from "view" to "paint") and pick the color from here

[image].

Comment: But I haven't a texture really. There is only vertex color data in vertex paint mode. The question wording is not the best.